# Declare a variable created inside of a class as a global variable

Tags: php

How do I make a variable that is created within a class function available outside of that class function?

For instance, the constructor of my main class creates an instance of the logging class. I want this $log variable to be available in other classes (using the global keyword) I would assume.

Is this possible?

Comment: Using the `global` keyword in the function that creates it, or `$GLOBALS['log']`, but you should rethink this.  Should the constructor of one class really be instantiating another which will be used globally? Probably you should be instantiating the logging class outside the other class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use static.

```
class Main
    {
    static private $log;

    public function __construct()
        {
        self::$log = new Log();
        }

    static public function getLog()
        {
        return self::$log;
        }
    }
```

Now you can get access to $log everywhere using

```
Main::getLog();
```

Comment: Thanks.. that might be the path I take!

Answer (score 1):

Using a global would defeat the purpose of OOP. OOP is meant to alleviate dependence and provide code containment for modular use.

You are simply approaching your application design wrong, instead, design ease of access to the logging instance. That is; instantiate your logging class and store the instance somewhere that's accessible (by design) by other classes that depend on it. A sort of "registry".

Comment: Good answer.. your point about it defeating the purpose of OOP is very valid. I will rethink how I want this to work.